# Find consecutive elements and group all surronding divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm, grouping

[image]

Hello,

Let's say I have 4 boxes and between them 3 operators (AND|OR). Each time that I toggle between AND|OR, I need to group together boxes and operators based on the rule if two operators have the same consecutive value.

Some random scenarios that need a group:

> [B1 AND B2 AND B3] OR B4   (example from picture)
> B1 OR [B2 AND B3 AND B4]
> B1 AND [B2 OR B3 OR B4]

If I have 5 boxes with and different and consecutive operators it should prioritize and wrap only first group of operators.  For example: [B1 OR B2 OR B3] AND B4 AND B5.

So far this is my code but isn't working properly, especially in finding consecutive operators.  For example: [B1 OR B2 OR B3] AND B4 AND B5

HTML:

```
<div class="container-section">
    <div class="box">box1</div>
    <div class="and-or" data-operator="0">AND</div>
</div>

<div class="container-section">
    <div class="box">box2</div>
    <div class="and-or" data-operator="0">AND</div>
</div>

<div class="container-section">
    <div class="box">box3</div>
    <div class="and-or" data-operator="1">OR</div>
</div>

<div class="container-section">
    <div class="box">box4</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function groupBoxes() {

    //find all operators,
    let operators = $('.and-or');

    //reset all groups
    $('.container-section').removeClass('hasGroup');
    $('.group-blue-line > .container-section').unwrap();

    //trying to find consecutive operators
    //foreach operator I am trying to look up and down to siblings value

    operators.each(function(index, element) {
        let currentOperator = $(element);
        let prevOperator = $(operators[index - 1]);
        let nextOperator = $(operators[index + 1]);
        let prevBox = $(element).closest('.container-section').prev();
        let nextBox = $(element).closest('.container-section').next();

        if (prevOperator && currentOperator.data('operator') == prevOperator.data('operator')) {
            prevBox.addClass('hasGroup');
        }

        if (nextOperator && currentOperator.data('operator') == nextOperator.data('operator')) {
            nextBox.addClass('hasGroup');
        }
    });
    $('.hasGroup').wrapAll('<div class="group-blue-line"></div>');
}
```

Comment: Hi, something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4yhnqL6f/) you can do